# Designing a container page

Tags: php, html

Are there any potentiall pitfalls with the following idea:

> ...I want to have one container page, index.php. The header and outlines will be constant but in the middle I want one big panel, which loads its content from external php files, one for each "slide". When a user click a link, the central div will update with the new content, the outer edge will remain unchanged.

Will I be able to use session variables, etc correctly with the set-up. I realise it will certainly break the browser history but other than some possible UI issues, are there any techincal barriers.

Comment: People do this all the time with `iframes`, `frames`, and AJAX-loaded content.

Comment: You shouldn't really worry about breaking the history. There are lots of solutions to this. Look at http://ajaxhistory.com/example/, for instance.

Comment: Also, sessions if used will continue to work, although you may have to accommodate if a session expires (for instance, if a login is required to view your content).

Comment: BTW: does anyone know if this technique has a commonly used name so that I can continue to Google about about it more easily. The idea can be hard to explain. I was also wondering if there were any jQuery libraries for helping with it?

Comment: @Patrick: "Web development". Jared already listed the three main technologies involved in making this work (one at a time only).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The session should not be lost.

The browser history does not need to be lost also - please read about `onPopState` (and `history.pushState`) and `onHashChange` JS events. The AJAX-heavy sites can determine the content to be loaded that way.

One of the pitfails is, if you are using a lot of JS, that the events for the newly loaded content will need to be re-attached, but they can also be delegated from the container which is not replaced.

jQuery's `.load()` function may be also useful to you to get started.

Comment: True that, also if you use jQuery you can use `.live()` so you don't have to reattach events:)

Comment: @Trey `.live()` is actually doing what I meant by delegating events, except that I would rather suggest using `.delegate()` than `.live()` as it seems to be more efficient and less messy.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "delegated". I was wondering if JS would actually be my biggest probelm. If each "slide" had its own JS file, how could I keep each slide with the correct script?

Comment: @Patrick Beardmore: I would not use separate files, I would rather separate the code within the single file logically, eg. into classes that are initialized depending on which page is loaded. And yes, JS may be one of your issues, because the content will change and the events can be deleted, replaced, cumulated etc. - just think about JS a while. What I meant is using `.delegate()` function like in their [first demo](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) - you do not need to re-attach events within the container, as long as the container is not replaced nor deleted. Am I clear enough?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common thing, as Jared stated. Session variables are always available through ajax or frames, so it shouldn't affect anything there, and if browser history is something you would like to continue to use, you could always change your location.hash when you load new content so that you can load previously rendered content with some javascript if someone uses the back or forward buttons.

Comment: changing `location.href` will redirect the browser - what he needs is `history.pushState` and `onPopState`, as I described in my answer. For older browsers changing location.hash (eg. using _hashbang_) should do the work.

Comment: `location.href=location.href+'#a';` won't do anything more than clicking on a link with `href="#a"` does, but I do like your approach better

Comment: Thanks. But I suggest `location.hash = '#a';` looks better ;)